Sort shapes' content in Word using Excel
I've shapes in Word with content inside it, and I want to sort the order of the content in all shapes based on the order in Excel sheet 2 column A.
In the doc I've content like this for example-
Type 1
content
content
content
Type 2
content
Type 3

Now in Excel sheet there is a Type order in Excel sheet which should be followed.
In above example, the Type 1 and Type 2 are the Type, and the content/lines after Type 1 and before Type 2 will be associated with Type 1 and content after Type 2 and before Type 3 will be associated with Type 2.
Now for example if the in Excel sheet the Type 2 comes first, and Type 1 comes second so the final output would be-
Type 2
content
Type 1
content
content
content
Type 3

the text could be anything inside the shapes, but I just wanted to give a logic which I would like to use. Could someone provide me with the VBA script for this?
Sub SortShapesContentBasedOnExcelOrder()
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim shape As shape
    Dim excelApp As Object
    Dim excelWB As Object
    Dim excelSheet As Object
    Dim typeOrder As Collection
    Dim shapeContents As Collection
    Dim sortedShapeContents As Collection
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim typeName As Variant ' Ensure it's a Variant to accept any type of data from the collection
    Dim shapeContent As Variant ' Declare shapeContent as Variant
    Dim shapeData As Collection
    Dim startPos As Integer
    
    ' Set the Word Document
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Debug.Print "Document set to ActiveDocument"
    
    ' Initialize Excel Application
    Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    excelApp.Visible = False ' Keep Excel invisible
    Debug.Print "Excel Application started"
    
    ' Open the Excel Workbook
    Set excelWB = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\vijva\Downloads\Updated Fields.xlsx") ' Update path to your Excel file
    Set excelSheet = excelWB.Sheets("Sheet2") ' Sheet2 is where the Type order is
    Debug.Print "Excel Workbook opened: " & excelWB.Name
    
    ' Get the Type order from Excel sheet column A
    Set typeOrder = New Collection
    i = 1
    Debug.Print "Reading Type Order from Excel:"
    Do While excelSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
        typeOrder.Add excelSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
        Debug.Print "Added " & excelSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value & " to typeOrder"
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    
    ' Initialize collection to hold shape contents
    Set shapeContents = New Collection
    Debug.Print "Initialized shapeContents collection"
    
    ' Loop through all shapes in the Word document
    Debug.Print "Looping through shapes in the Word document:"
    For Each shape In doc.Shapes
        If shape.Type = msoTextBox Then
            shapeContent = shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
            Debug.Print "Found TextBox shape with content: " & shapeContent
            
            ' Check if shape contains a "Type" (e.g., "SEALANT", "TOOLS")
            For Each typeName In typeOrder
                If InStr(shapeContent, typeName) > 0 Then
                    ' Store shape's type and content as a pair
                    Set shapeData = New Collection
                    shapeData.Add typeName ' Add type
                    shapeData.Add shapeContent ' Add content
                    shapeContents.Add shapeData ' Add shape data to collection
                    Debug.Print "Added shape with type " & typeName & " to shapeContents"
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next typeName
        End If
    Next shape
    
    ' Sort the shapes based on Excel order
    Set sortedShapeContents = New Collection
    Debug.Print "Sorting shape contents based on Type order:"
    For Each typeName In typeOrder
        For Each shapeData In shapeContents
            If shapeData(1) = typeName Then
                sortedShapeContents.Add shapeData(2)
                Debug.Print "Added content for " & typeName & " to sortedShapeContents"
            End If
        Next shapeData
    Next typeName
    
    ' Now update the Word document with sorted content
    Debug.Print "Constructing new text for Word document:"
    
    ' Delete existing shapes before adding new ones
    Debug.Print "Deleting existing shapes in the document:"
    For Each shape In doc.Shapes
        Debug.Print "Deleting shape: " & shape.Name ' Print before deletion
        shape.Delete
    Next shape
    
    ' Add sorted content as new shapes
    startPos = 0
    For Each shapeContent In sortedShapeContents
        Set shape = doc.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 100, 100 + startPos, 300, 50)
        shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = shapeContent
        Debug.Print "Added shape with content: " & shapeContent
        startPos = startPos + 60 ' Adjust position for next shape
    Next shapeContent
    
    ' Close Excel without saving
    excelWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
    excelApp.Quit
    Set excelApp = Nothing
    Set excelWB = Nothing
    Set excelSheet = Nothing
    Debug.Print "Excel closed and objects cleaned up"
End Sub


@VKK please describe what is not working. Have you checked the if all the Debug.Print  outputs the expected values?

Everything is working, I'm not getting any error but the content inside the shapes is not getting sorted.

So e.g. the content in Type 1 shall also be sorted (according the excel worksheet or alphabetical)? If you please describe this in your question.

@Shrotter According to the order in Excel.

@VKK have you considered, to remove all shapes and generate them directly from the data in the worksheet? Or does the worksheet not contain the same date?

In the Excel I have the order for the type and based on this order the content inside the shapes should be sorted. You'll understand better if you read my question again with the example I provided.

@VKK If all data is included in the worksheet (and sorted there), you could remove all sorting and collections from your code and create the shapes according the worksheet data

Only Types are there in the worksheet. Do you have a solution for this?
